# DOMPDF produces gibberish

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

I have followed the instructions on http://www.syahzul.com/cakephp/how-to-generate-pdf-in-cakephp-2-x-with-dompdf/ and installed DOMPDF version 0.6.1.
When I press the PDF button on my view page, I get gibberish displayed. (see below). I have checked that the fonts are installed in the classes library.
Any suggestions?

**Step 2 (in /app/Config/routes.php**

```
    Router::parseExtensions('pdf');
```

**Step 3 (in ChecksController.php)**

```
    class ChecksController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session', 'RequestHandler');
```

**Step 4 (in /app/View/Layouts/pdf/default.ctp)**

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS 
.dompdf_config.inc.php');
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper = 'A4';
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

**Step 5 (in ChecksController.php)**

```
public function view_pdf($id = null) {
$this->Check->id = $id;
if (!$this->Check->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Check'));
}
// increase memory limit in PHP
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
$this->set('check', $this->Check->read(null, $id));
```

**Step 6 (in checks\app\View\Checks\pdf\view_pdf.ctp)**

```
<div class="checks view">
<h2><?php echo __('Check Flight'); ?></h2>
<?php //echo debug($check); ?>
<dl>
    <dt><?php echo __('Instructor'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Instructor']['first'] . ' ' . $check['Instructor']['last']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Pilot'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Person']['first'] . ' ' .  $check['Person']['last']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Flight Date'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Check']['flight_date']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Check Type'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Check']['check_type']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Aircraft'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Aircraft']['registration']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Hours'); ?></dt>
    <dd>    <?php echo h($check['Check']['hours']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Conditions'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Check']['conditions']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Passed'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Check']['passed']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Notes'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($check['Check']['notes']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <div class='items'>
        <dt><?php echo __('Additional Areas'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php foreach ($check['Assessment'] as $assessment): ?>
                    <?php  echo h($assessment['description']); ?><br/>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dd>
     </div>   
</dl>
```

**Step 7 (in app\View\Checks\view.ctp)**

```
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('PDF'), array('action' => 'view_pdf', 'ext' => 'pdf', $check['Check']['id']));?></li>
```

**Output:**

```
%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R /OpenAction 8 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 9 0 R /F2 10 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (dompdf) /CreationDate (D:20150315060510+01'00') /ModDate (D:20150315060510+01'00') >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 349 >> stream x�m��k�0���W�c�D�ڷ�ha��>��C�H�5�5�����Ӵ}I�K>�~sw����a�wq�d�@�������s��6�i ��1� �/�$",�ȸ?`��s�E��4bL�vqϯa$�3�#��g��xJ�����T�+�A�U�jSA�K�?wѧ=ʦ�[]�y���"0���?���|x��(lfd+�,��������PUf!2s����數r}@]I��z��>�$�:|��x됣�qpFf�\�|>��9�KS§nލ��֏ �#���y���tpJ+;�Mv�5G����5LUۦu�Q�Up.�V'!܈��͇yܻ�(m}q��e� endstream endobj 8 0 obj [6 0 R /Fit] endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Times-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj xref 0 11 0000000000 65535 f 0000000008 00000 n 0000000091 00000 n 0000000137 00000 n 0000000302 00000 n 0000000331 00000 n 0000000445 00000 n 0000000508 00000 n 0000000929 00000 n 0000000957 00000 n 0000001065 00000 n trailer << /Size 11 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 1175 %%EOF
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gibberish"? It's difficult to diagnose your PDF because the internal formatting is lost. You could either post a screen shot, update the question with the formatted PDF source, or link to the file. It would also help to see the expected HTML (everything else looks reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

it's probably this line:

```
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
```

$content_for_layout is deprecated: use `$this->fetch('content')` instead.

Comment: No, that did not work: I also tried $dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($this->fetch('content')), Configure::read('App.encoding'));

Comment: This line should still be changed. In addition to the change suggested in the answer you should remove `utf8_decode()`. It's not necessary and is harmful to documents that contain non-ascii characters.

Comment: as I said, I tried $dompdf->load_html($this->fetch('content')); and $dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($this->fetch('content'), Configure::read('App.encoding')); and neither worked

Comment: Is there any step in the setup above that is incorrect, or something perhaps omitted?

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting. If it's just to remove the utf8()  as below, it makes no difference  $dompdf->load_html($this->fetch('content'), Configure::read('App.encoding'));

Comment: I got it working: I commented out the require_once in the Layouts/pdf/default.ctp, and added some html after the fetch statement, but before the spl_autoload statement.

Comment: can u post what is your new code now, it will help me and many more finding solution of this